# store both text and number in sql

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

How can store both text and integer in same field in sql?

Want to store like this: ex: Jh_123

Am using phpmyadmin.

And also want to use as "UNIQUE" field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [NVARCHAR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) data type to keep text and numbers.

> Character data types that are either fixed-length, nchar, or
>   variable-length, nvarchar, Unicode data and use the UNICODE UCS-2
>   character set.

---

As in your comment, would be like:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
Id INT,
Name  NVARCHAR(50) UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1, 'Jh_123')

SELECT * FROM Test
```

And result will be: `1 Jh_123`

Comment: ok thank you can i save it as "Unique" filed in database(phpmyadmin)?

Comment: Yes, you can do It. Also you can use simple `VARCHAR` if you won't use unicode (custom) characters.

Comment: @Shalom updated my answer with sample code. If that worked for you don't forget to accept as correct answer.

Comment: shows an error "Duplicate entry" when i store index as UNIQUE

Comment: If you set It to unique, all values inside should be distinct (can't be duplicated)

Comment: Thank God, it solved when tick on "NULL" field. Is there any problem "UNIQUE" value accepts NULL?

Comment: Unique can have only 1 null (can't be duplicates in column). Do not forget to accept as correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

use nvarchar(max)  then retrieve data by putting where condition

when u want to get only int values then you can use

```
 where column>0
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.actually,">0" means length or count ?is it? then how it call only integer?

Comment: if u write that condition then it will takes that column and automatically converts to int and checks ... if any alphabet or another present in a specific row then it is rejected